# How to use enable_if to pick a different function for numbes and non-numbers?

Tags: c++

I want two versions of a template function, one for number types and one for non-number types. When the type is number, I want the parameters passed by value, otherwise by reference.

I tried this but it doesn't work (VS2015):

```
template <class T>
T& as_number(typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type& x)
{
    return x;
}

template<class T>
T as_number(typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type x)
{
    return x;
}
```

`error C2783: 'T as_number(std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<_Ty>::value,T>::type)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'`

How do I get this to work? (I did try several other variations but they didn't work either)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your functions would work if you explicitly specified type T as it cannot be deduced the way it is now. You'd have to do: `as_number<int>(10);` for example where you explicitly specify T = int.

However, if you pass T as a parameter, then it can deduce the type of parameter and still allow you to use `enable_if` but on the return type instead.

http://ideone.com/IsiHnr

```
#include <iostream>


template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type& as_number(T& x)
{
    std::cout<<"By Reference\n";
    return x;
}

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type as_number(T x)
{
    std::cout<<"By Value\n";
    return x;
}

class Foo
{

};

int main()
{
    as_number(10);

    Foo f;
    as_number(f);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If the function needs to return void or another type.. Then use a default template argument:

http://ideone.com/gZS5N3 OR even better (in my opinion): http://ideone.com/oObjzj

```
#include <iostream>


template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
void as_number(T& x)
{
    std::cout<<"By Reference\n";
}

template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
void as_number(T x)
{
    std::cout<<"By Value\n";
}

class Foo
{

};

int main()
{
    as_number(10);

    Foo f;
    as_number(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Personally I like putting the function title and arguments on one line, and the templating, return value, etc. above it. Thanks for the info none the less, I still figured it out.

Comment: What if the functions returned void?

Comment: @NeilKirk I edited the post to add such an example (two very similar [one with int as default and the other using typename default]). There are other techniques too (using decltype, result_of, etc..).